# How to track the packets transmitted in Bluetooth Low Energy signal?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, signals, packet

I am making an Android app for transmitting and scanning BLE signals for an experiment. I need the metric for how many packets are advertised by the transmitting device and how many are received by the scanning device. Is it possible to obtain these numbers?

Here is my advertisement code :

```
private void transmit() {   

        disableScanBtn();

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();



        switch (advParameter){
            case 0 :
                advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH;
                advSetting = "High";
                break;

            case 1 :
                advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MEDIUM;
                advSetting = "Medium";
                break;
            case 2 :
                advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_LOW;
                advSetting = "Low";
                break;
            case 3 :

                advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MIN;
                advSetting = "Min";
                break;
            default:
                advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MAX;
                advSetting = "Max";
        }

        AdvertisingSetParameters parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                .setInterval(advInterval)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
                .setConnectable(true)
                .build();

        deviceId = Installation.id ( this );
        ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.fromString( deviceId ) );
        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .addServiceUuid( pUuid )
                .addServiceData( pUuid, "Data".getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) )
                .build();

        mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertisingSetCallback () {

            @Override
            public void onAdvertisingSetStarted(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet,
                                                int txPower,
                                                int status) {
                super.onAdvertisingSetStarted (advertisingSet, txPower, status);
            
                Toast.makeText( BluetoothActivity.this, "Started "+ status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdvertisingSetStopped(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertising onStartFailure: ");
                super.onAdvertisingSetStopped (advertisingSet);
            }
        };

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters, data, null,null,null, mAdvertiseCallback);
        mTransmitTime.setText ( String.valueOf (System.currentTimeMillis ()));

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void stopTransmit() {


            enableScanBtn();


        if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser != null) {
                mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertisingSet(mAdvertiseCallback);

        }
    }
```

Here is my scanning code:

```
private final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback () {


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

            super.onScanResult ( callbackType, result );


            if (mList.size () > 0) {
                try {
                    mList.clear ();
                    mArrayAdapter.clear ();
                    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                    rssi = result.getRssi ();
                    id = result.getDevice ().getAddress ();

                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }

            if (result == null || result.getDevice () == null) {
                Log.e ( TAG, "-> No devices found" );
                return;
            }

            try {


                name = result.getScanRecord ().getDeviceName ();
                id = result.getDevice ().getAddress ();


                time= System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (String.valueOf ( name ) != "null"){
                    addItemToSheet ( String.valueOf(rssi), id, time );
                }


                String apDetails = "AP: " + name + "\n" +
                        "UUID: " + id + "\n" +
                        "RSSI: " + rssi + "\n" +
                        "Time : " + time;

                Log.i ( TAG, apDetails );

                mList.add ( apDetails );


            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                Log.e ( TAG, e.getMessage () );
            }

            mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<> ( getApplicationContext (),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList );
            mListView.setAdapter ( mArrayAdapter );
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {

            super.onBatchScanResults ( results );
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {

            super.onScanFailed ( errorCode );
            Toast.makeText ( BluetoothActivity.this, "onScanFailed: " + String.valueOf ( errorCode ), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();
        }

    };
```

Is there a way to count the number of packets in the given code?

Comment: Did you try simply having a counter field which you increment in the "onScanResult" callback? Am I missing something which would make it not good enough for what you need?

Comment: No I didn't, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: I think each scanresult specifies a scanned packet right?

Comment: I initialized a `count` variable to 0 in the beginning of the `transmit()` method and set `count+=1` in the `AdvertisingSetStarted` method but its value just stays 1 throughout the Advertising period

Comment: No, adding a counter won't work because the callbacks aren't invoked _every time_ the `AdvertiseData` is advertised.  So you can't check the packets transmitted at the Java layer. You could _possibly_ try monitoring the traffic on the BLE interface on the target device after enabling **Bluetooth HCI snoop logs** from Developer Settings and then analysing it in Wireshark.